# a-star shortest path algorithm's question

Tags: shortest-path, a-star

[image]

Map is that picture(10x10) and can not be moved diagonally.

Search order is up, right, down, left.

then, if run a-star shortest algorithm is running like black path, isn't it?

but shortest path is red path.

I do not understand a-star algorithm well. I want you to help me.

Comment: To me it sounds like there is a bug in your implementation. However, there is no way we can help you with that unless you post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your search is tree search(repetitive states are allowed)and your heuristic function is admissible(your function underestimate the real cost, you can read more about it in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic)) then A* guarantee the optimality of found path. (In graph search, the h function must be consistent).You might be chosen the overestimated h function. One good h function for your question could be Manhattan distance